# Correct return type from web API

Tags: c#, swagger-ui, asp.net-core-2.2

I am creating a c# .net core 2.2 web API for my next project. My question is when returning data should I return the object or `IActionResult OK(returnObject)`?

The reason I ask is I am using swagger and swagger studio to create my models for an Angular front end. If I return an `IActionResult` from the API the returned view models are not detailed in the `swagger.json` file so I would have to code these in the angular application. If I return whatever object is created the model is created in the `swagger.json`.

What practice should I follow to return data from an API in this case?

Comment: The [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/action-return-types?view=aspnetcore-2.2) cover this well.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You do want to return `IActionResult(object)` but you are not quite done.

Annotate your controller with the `ProducesAttribute` and annotate your method with the `ProducesResponseTypeAttribute`:

```
[Produces("application/json")]
public class SomethingController
{
    [ProducesResponseType(typeof(YourObject), (int)HttpStatusCode.OK)]
    public IActionResult GetThing(int id)
    { ... }
}
```

This allows Swagger UI to know what to expect and document it appropriately. Shown above is for a synchronous method; it works for asynchronous as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can return 
- Specific Type
- IActionResult
- ActionResult

For more details, please refer MSDN article at : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/action-return-types?view=aspnetcore-2.2